# Watch Face with additional styles in Gear S2 on Tizen SDK

Tags: javascript, html, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, watch-face-api

I'm working on developing various watch faces for the Gears S2 under the Tizen Web SDK.

I've noticed some of the preinstalled watch faces have a "Style" button at the bottom of the watch chooser screen. When this button is tapped, a page full of options appears enabling the user to change the color, as well as other watch face options.

I cannot find any API that allows me to put this same button on my watch faces in order to provide a color changing UI. Anyone here have any ideas?

I've already tried the sample applications. None of them have that button. Is this a manufacturer only option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those options are not available for outside developers. Those are only available for samsung partnered developers.

Comment: Yeah I got an email from a Samsung support dev saying the same thing. Thanks for taking the time to respond anyway.