# Is there any way to let user change and customize Tizen web watch face?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, samsung-galaxy-gear, watchface, samsung-gear-s2

I have created a watch face for tizen using tizen-web-app.
it works fine but it's completely permanent and users can't change it at all.
I wanted to know if there is any way to make options (like 'stylize' in native apps) to provide the ability of changing the watch for the user, just like background color?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watch Face with additional styles in Gear S2 on Tizen SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100769/watch-face-with-additional-styles-in-gear-s2-on-tizen-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Those options are not available for **outside(3rd party)** developers. Those are only available for samsung partnered developers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add customize event for change options (background color, wallpaper etc.), at the same time you need to pre-load those  with your app.